# ADMA0207E Error when deploying EAR on IBM WAS 7 but not on IBM WAS 6.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, ear, websphere-7, ibm-was

I am getting the ADMA0207E error when deploying an Enterprise Archive (EAR) file to IBM Websphere Application Server (WAS) 7 but not when I deploy the same EAR to WAS 6.

**Error:**

```
servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [isclite] [/ibm/console] [/secure/javascriptToSession.jsp]: Initialization successful.
SystemErr     R com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException: ADMA0207E: EE 5 module foo-web.war in ear file contains unsupported xmi format bindings file.
SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.checkIfEE5ModulesContainXMIBindings(AppInstallHelper.java:1066)
SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.checkForEE5Restrictions(AppInstallHelper.java:324)
SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.getAppDeploymentInfoGenericRead(AppInstallHelper.java:469)
SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.DefaultBindingHelper.getDefaultBindingInfo(DefaultBindingHelper.java:101)
SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.DefaultBindingHelper.getDefaultBindingInfo(DefaultBindingHelper.java:91)
SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.console.appmanagement.action.UploadAction.formUpload(UploadAction.java:491)
SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.console.appmanagement.action.UploadAction.execute(UploadAction.java:156)
```

I want to deploy this EAR on WAS 7. Any insight on getting past this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application version is not consistent with metadata files.
`ADMA0207E: EE 5 module foo-web.war in ear file contains unsupported xmi format bindings file.`

If you want to use Java EE 5, then you have to **update** `ibm-web-bnd.xmi` to  `ibm-web-bnd.xml` (the best to do it with development tool RAD or WDT for Eclipse, **DO NOT rename**), or you have to have Java EE 1.4 descriptors `(application.xml` and `web.xml`).
You can also **remove** the binding files, and recreate these bindings during application installation. It will create binding file in the new, correct format.

> Supported configurations: For IBM® extension and binding files, the
>   `.xmi` or `.xml` file name extension is different depending on whether you
>   are using a pre-Java EE 5 application or module or a Java EE 5 or
>   later application or module. An IBM extension or binding file is named
>   `ibm-*-ext.xmi` or `ibm-*-bnd.xmi` where * is the type of extension or
>   binding file such as `app, application, ejb-jar, or web`. The following
>   conditions apply:
>
> - For an application or module that uses a Java EE version prior to version 5, the file extension must be `.xmi`.
> - For an application or module that uses Java EE 5 or later, the file extension must be `.xml`. If `.xmi` files are included with the
>     application or module, the product ignores the `.xmi` files.

See also:

- [PK78515: Application deployment error](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK78515)

Comment: I inherited this code and the _WEB-INF directory_ contains _ibm-web-bnd.xmi_. So I guess this is meant for Java 1.4 or earlier but I want to deploy it on WAS 8. Any insight?

Comment: @javaPlease42 I don't understand what more you are asking for. I gave you 3 possible solutions: fix descriptors, update bnd file, or remove the file (and provide bindings during installation). What else are you expecting? Add contents of `ibm-web-bnd.xmi` file to the question, so I can see, if you can safely delete it.